# read each word in string into pandas new row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below string.
msg='The managing director of the IMF'
I want pandas dataframe like below
['The'
  'managing'
  'director'
  'of'
  'the'
  'IMF'
]
1 column & 6 rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
msg='The managing director of the IMF'
df = pd.DataFrame(msg.split(), columns=['col'])
print (df)
        col
0       The
1  managing
2  director
3        of
4       the
5       IMF
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame([msg.split()], columns=list('abcdef'))
print (df)
     a         b         c   d    e    f
0  The  managing  director  of  the  IMF
```

Alternative:

```
msg='The managing director of the IMF'
L = msg.split()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(L).reshape(-1, len(L)), columns=list('abcdef'))
print (df)
     a         b         c   d    e    f
0  The  managing  director  of  the  IMF
```

Comment: its 1 row 6 columns
i want 1 column 6 rows.

Comment: df.T will transpose it.

Comment: @AshishBainade - Glad can help you.